Redirect all http request for spicial address to another server
I want to say  that all special http web requests from the Linux server go to asb.com, first to an intermediate server and then send to asb.com server.
That is, I don't want the requests to go directly from the main server to  asb.com server, I want there to be an intermediary server that goes through those requests and gets the answer and returns it to the main server.

The correct jargon for that would be a “web proxy” or “reverse proxy”; which to use depends a bit on your deployment scenario and requirements, which I can’t quite understand based on your question.

Sounds like you need a proxy, take a look at squid: https://www.squid-cache.org/
